# Google Breakpad fails to compile

Tags: python, crash-reports, crash-dumps, google-breakpad

I am attempting to build [google-breakpad](http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/) and I am getting the error

```
  File "C:\google-breakpad\src\tools\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 907, in _GetPathDict
    parent_dict = _GetPathDict(root, parent)
  File "C:\google-breakpad\src\tools\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 906, in _GetPathDict
    parent, folder = os.path.split(path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 170, in split
    d, p = splitdrive(p)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 125, in splitdrive
    if p[1:2] == ':':
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

When I run the command

```
src\tools\gyp\gyp.bat src\client\windows\breakpad_client.gyp
```

Does anyone know if Google-Breakpad is broken or how I may fix this error?

Comment: would be cool to know what Google breakpad is, maybe with a link.

Comment: ...and what it has to do with app engine

Comment: I'd file a bug. This kind of error look strangely like a long-unmaintained code rot.

Comment: The problem is with another tool by Google, ``gyp``. [Issue 141 of gyp](http://code.google.com/p/gyp/issues/detail?id=141) reports that same error message as yours. A workaround posted there might help.

Comment: @ento: Why don't you post your finding as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a misinstalled python.

Comment: Can you go in to more detail? What specifically did you do to address this? I'm getting the same error and don't know what I might have done in the Python config process that would have caused it to be misconfigured.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it'll fix your problem or not, but you could always consider raising the maximum recursion depth.  Python allows you to configure it by using a function called sys.setrecursionlimit().  The default limit from what I can gather is 1000, so you might have luck by increasing it to, say, 1500 or 2000.

The python documentation isn't terribly friendly here, only saying that the maximum recursion limit is platform dependent, but give it a shot and see if it works.